# Get all pixels location

Tags: pixel, autoit

I know how to find 1 **pixel** that matches my criteria, but the problem is that I would like to find all **pixels** of specific **color** and add them to **array**, so after that I can use it to **rand** one and "click" on it.

Source code:

```
Local $aCoord = PixelSearch(0, 0, $clientSize[0], $clientSize[1], 0x09126C, 10, 1, $hWnd)
If Not @error Then
    ; add to array and search next
Else
    GUICtrlSetData($someLabel, "Not Found")
EndIf
```

I want to find **ALL THE PIXELS**, not only "the first" one. How can I achieve that? What am I missing?

Comment: I think any plain Autoit solution is likely to be rather slow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This **can't** be done using [`PixelSearch`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/PixelSearch.htm) because it stops executing when a matching pixel is found.

It can be done by looping [`PixelGetColor`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/PixelGetColor.htm) over your area. Something like:

```
For $x = 0 To $clientSize[0] Step 1
   For $y = 0 To $clientSize[1] Step 1
      If PixelGetColor($x,$y,$hWnd) = 0x09126C Then
         ;Add $x and $y to Array using _ArrayAdd() (or whatever you prefer)
      EndIf
   Next
Next
```

This might feel slower than [`PixelSearch`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/PixelSearch.htm) because it now has to scan the entire area, instead of stopping at the first match, but it shouldn't be, since [`PixelSearch`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/PixelGetColor.htm) is based on the same principle.

Comment: It may be possible to implement something faster using this: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/126430-advanced-pixel-search-library/